# Sending multipart body from Retrofit2 and processing it in ASP Core

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core, retrofit2, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently sending an Order object from an Android app with Retrofit2

```
@PUT("orders/insert")
Call<Order> putOrders(@Body Order order);
```

and getting it my ASP Core web api like this:

```
[HttpPut("api/orders/update")]
    public async Task UpdateOrder([FromBody] Order order)
    {
        await OrdersRepository.UpdateOrder(order);
    }
```

But now I want to also attach an image to my request. Initially I've tried converting the image to a byte[] array in my Android app and passing it as part of my Order object but that resulted in getting a null order in the API (smaller byte arrays seemed to work though) so I decided to send the image in a multipart body request.

My problem is I'm not sure if I'm properly creating the request in Retrofit2 nor how to process it from a request into a file and an Order object in the API since there can only be one [FromBody] attritbute.

This is how I defined my Retrofit2 interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("uploadAttachmentorders/uploadfile")
Call<Order> uploadSignature(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart, @Part("Order") Order order);
```

And this is how the actual call looks:

```
        Order order = orders.getOrders().get(0);
        File clientSignatureFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),order.getId().toString());
        clientSignatureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(clientSignatureFile);
        fos.write(order.getClientSignature());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", clientSignatureFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), clientSignatureFile));

        Call<Order> callFile = apiService.uploadSignature(filePart,order);
```

Comment: Could you share an example of your request?

Comment: @AlexRiabov l'm not sure what you mean. I don' do anything extra to the request beyond what I posted I just do callFile.enqueue where I will check the response

Comment: @GeorgeTodosi Try to swapping the parameters in your uploadSignature method. I had an issue with this that my image was not being uploaded on the server, after passing the image at the last parameter help me resolve that. See if that can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should create a request of multipart/form-data type. Asp.Net Core has built-in class `IFormFile` to support file uploading. You can create a model with a property of that type and a property with your model:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public Order Order { get;set; }

    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

And your method should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateOrder(OrderViewModel ovm)
{
    var order = ovm.Order;

    if (ovm.File != null)
    {
        byte[] fileData = null;

        // read file to byte array
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(ovm.File.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)ovm.File.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to only be partially working. The file is being sent and recieved but the Order is null. I've had to set a name for the part in Retrofit2 otherwise I would get an exception (I updated the OP to match). Do I need to set an attribute in the ViewModel that matches or something similar?

Comment: @GeorgeTodosi what values do you have in `Request.Keys` in CreateOrder method?

Comment: I don't have such a method. I think my API might not be implemented in the most proper way. But I've managed to find a solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979737/model-binding-for-multipart-form-data-file-json-post-in-asp-net-core-1-1 I used the custom model binder class there and added the attribute to the Order property in OrderViewModel and it seems to work now.