# Parse multipart response C# .net standard

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, .net-standard-2.0

I call API to get a multipart response like this

```
------------cH2ae0GI3KM7GI3Ij5ae0ei4Ij5Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filename\"

PB020344.jpg
------------cH2ae0GI3KM7GI3Ij5ae0ei4Ij5Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"PB020344.jpg\"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

BINARY DATA IS HERE
------------cH2ae0GI3KM7GI3Ij5ae0ei4Ij5Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Upload\"

Submit Query
------------cH2ae0GI3KM7GI3Ij5ae0ei4Ij5Ij5-
```

my question is there a simpler way to extract the data in  .net standard, I have class library with a method

```
private static byte[] ParseResponse(
    byte[] responseStreamBytes,
    out List<string> responseHeaders,
    ref int startIndex ) {
    try {

        const byte CR = (byte)'\r';
        const byte NEWLINE = (byte)'\n';
        const byte HYPHEN = (byte)'-';
        List<string> responseFileParams = new List<string>();
        int nonDicomCount = 0;
        //Figure out start of pixel byte array           
        for (int i = startIndex; i < responseStreamBytes.Length; i++) {
            if (responseStreamBytes[i] == CR) {
                if (responseStreamBytes[i + 1] == NEWLINE) {
                    string boundray = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                        responseStreamBytes,
                        startIndex,
                        i - startIndex);
                    responseFileParams.Add(boundray);
                    nonDicomCount += boundray.Length;
                    //Initial header and start of pixel data
                    //Skip \r\n
                    startIndex = i = i + 2;
                    if (boundray.Contains("Content-Location")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        responseHeaders = responseFileParams;
        startIndex += 2;
        //Keep count of non dicom data. Add 4 to skip CR
        nonDicomCount = nonDicomCount + 4;
        string endBoundary = responseFileParams[0]; // + "--";
        List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();
        //Collect all pixel bytes in an array
        for (int r = startIndex; r < responseStreamBytes.Length; r++) {
            if (responseStreamBytes[r] == CR && responseStreamBytes[r + 1] == NEWLINE) {
                if (
                    responseStreamBytes[r + 2] == HYPHEN &&
                    responseStreamBytes[r + 3] == HYPHEN
                ) {
                    //End of DICOM data
                    //r+2 to skip \r\n
                    string endBoundaryInArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                        responseStreamBytes,
                        r + 2,
                        endBoundary.Length);
                    if (
                        string.Compare(
                            endBoundary,
                            endBoundaryInArray,
                            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                    ) {
                        startIndex = r + 2;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            byteList.Add(responseStreamBytes[r]);
        }

        return byteList.ToArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        responseHeaders = new List<string>();
        return responseStreamBytes;
    }
}
```

I wonder if in .net standard, or there's a simpler way to extract the byte data

Comment: Are you using asp.net core? then you could use a custom modelbinder to handle this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979737/model-binding-for-multipart-form-data-file-json-post-in-asp-net-core-1-1)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts .NET standard class library

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source library for this called [Http-Multipart-Data-Parser](https://github.com/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser) that would help you do this. You can download and install it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpMultipartParser/). This is the parser I use and recommend in projects that use [Grapevine](https://github.com/scottoffen/grapevine).